# How to solve ' RenderBox was not laid out:' in flutter in a card widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a card that has three containers. The first two have text and the last one is supposed to hold a TextFormField alongside some text. So i have a row to hold the two along one another. Only thing is when i add the TextFormField widget it does not appear and the console throws shows an error

```dart
    ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY 
    ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    I/flutter (14101): The following assertion was thrown during 
    performLayout():
    I/flutter (14101): BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
    I/flutter (14101): These invalid constraints were provided to 
    RenderRepaintBoundary's layout() function by the
    I/flutter (14101): following function, which probably computed the invalid 
    constraints in question:
    I/flutter (14101):   _RenderDecoration._layout.layoutLineBox 
    (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:750:11)
    I/flutter (14101): The offending constraints were:
    I/flutter (14101):   BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=100.0)



    I/flutter (14101): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: 
    RenderPadding#150b0 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
    I/flutter (14101): Another exception was thrown: 
    'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 310 
    pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
    I/flutter (14101): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: 
    RenderPhysicalShape#1d998 relayoutBoundary=up4
```

The code looks like

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 2.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.pink,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new RichText(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text: 'Some Text',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 17.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new RichText(
                    softWrap: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text:
                          'Some other text',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 17.0),
                      ),
                        ),
                      Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('adfa'),
                      Text('data'),
                      Form(
                        child: TextFormField(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`TextFormField` causes the issue. It needs constraints for width.
E.g. wrap it into Expanded widget or Container with width.

Comment: In my case the Expanded is the one causing the error

Answer (score 43):

**Error reason:**

`Row` expands in horizontal direction and so does the `TextField`, so we need to constrain the width of the `TextField`, you can try any of following to do so.

1. Use `Expanded`

   ```
    Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(child: TextField()),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. Use `Flexible`

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Flexible(child: TextField()),
     ],
   )
   ```
3. Wrap it in `Container` or `SizedBox` and provide `width`

   ```
   Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(width: 100, child: TextField()),
     ],
   )
   ```

Answer (score 31):

After spending much time, I found the solution as below:

Please add `shrinkWrap: true` inside `ListView.builder()`.

It helped me.

Comment: Although this solution may help in regard to having a ListView, OP does not have one in the posted code.

Answer (score 7):

I am replying in enhancement of [German Saprykin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/911289/german-saprykin) post, I was also getting the same below error

> ════════ (2) Exception caught by rendering library
>   ══════════════════════════ 
>   An InputDecorator,
>   which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded
>   width. This happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite
>   width constraint. For example, if the InputDecorator is contained by a
>   Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a
>   SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or
>   the TextField that contains it.
>   'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart': Failed assertion:
>   line 910 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity'
>   User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:    TextField
>   file:///C:/CommBack/My_Workplace/Flutter/wiremusic/wiremusic_dev/lib/wire/widgets/searchfield.dart:15:14
>   ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ (3) Exception caught by rendering library
>   ══════════════════════════ 
>   RenderBox was not
>   laid out: _RenderDecoration#b1ce0 relayoutBoundary=up26 NEEDS-PAINT
>   NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1681
>   pos 12: 'hasSize' User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget
>   was:    TextField
>   file:///C:/CommBack/My_Workplace/Flutter/wiremusic/wiremusic_dev/lib/wire/widgets/searchfield.dart:15:14
>   ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

because of this below earlier source lines.

```
return Container(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 230.0, minHeight: 25.0),
  child: TextField(),
);
```

because the TextField requires the ancestor `hasSize` explicitly and after mentioning the width explicitly to Container, the error disappeared like <kbd>Thanos</kbd>

```
return Container(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  width: 230,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 230.0, minHeight: 25.0),
  child: TextField(),
);
```

Hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 4):

if You Using ListView.builder And get this error then this is the solution

Use in builder==  shrinkWrap: true,

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: historyList.length,
   shrinkWrap: true, ///////////////////////Use This Line 
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return historyListItem(historyList[index]['text'], 60, () {}, false, size);
    },
 )
```

Comment: This answer is already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023212/12483095). Can you delete your post?